# ggplot2 can't draw a correct plot with only two or three data points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R to generate some plots of some metrics and getting nice results like this for data that has > 3 data points:

[image]

However, I'm noticing that for data with only a few values - I get very poor results.

If I draw a plot with only two data points, I get a blank plot.
[image]
foo_two_points.dat

```
cluster,account,current_database,action,operation,count,day
cluster19,col0063,col0063,foo_two,two_bar,10,2016-10-04 00:00:00-07:00
cluster61,dwm4944,dwm4944,foo_two,two_bar,2,2016-12-14 00:00:00-08:00
```

If I draw one data point, it works.
[image]
foo_one_point.dat

```
cluster,account,current_database,action,operation,count,day
cluster1,foo0424,foo0424,fooone,,2,2016-11-01 00:00:00-07:00
```

Three, it almost works, but isn't accurate.
[image]
foo_three_points.dat

```
cluster,account,current_database,action,operation,count,day
cluster23,col2225,col2225,foo_three,bar,9,2016-12-22 00:00:00-08:00
cluster23,col2225,col2225,foo_three,bar,1,2016-12-29 00:00:00-08:00
cluster12,red1782,red1782,foo_three,bar,2,2016-10-25 00:00:00-07:00
```

4, 5, etc. all seem fine
[image]

But two or three points - nope.

Here is my plot.r file:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

args<-commandArgs(TRUE)

filename<-args[1]
n = nchar(filename) - 4
thetitle = substring(filename, 1, n)
print(thetitle)
png_filename <- stringi::stri_flatten(stringi::stri_join(c(thetitle,'.png')))

wide<-as.numeric(args[2])
high<-as.numeric(args[3])
legend_left<-as.numeric(args[4])

pos <- if(legend_left == 1) c(1,0)  else c(0,1) 
place <- if(legend_left == 1) 'left'  else 'right'

print(wide)
print(high)

print(filename)
print(png_filename)

dat = read.csv(filename)

dat$account = as.character(dat$account)
dat$action=as.character(dat$action)
dat$operation = as.character(dat$operation)
dat$count = as.integer(dat$count)
dat$day = as.Date(dat$day)
dat[is.na(dat)]<-"N/A"

png(png_filename,width=wide,height=high)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=day, y=count, fill=account, labels=TRUE)) 
p <- p + geom_histogram(stat="identity") 
p <- p + scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%Y"), limits=as.Date(c('2016-10-01','2017-01-01')))
p <- p + theme(legend.position="bottom")
p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(size=15)) 
p<-p+labs(title=thetitle)

print(p)

dev.off()
```

Here's the command I use to run it:

```
RScript plot.r foo_five_points.dat 1600 800 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean, there are no bars?

Comment: Maybe you need `geom_bar` instead of `geom_histogram()`? one or two points with a histogram doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Well, for other reports with many many more rows of data - I get a stacked histogram which is what I want.  This is for an automated process, so I don't want to have to finesse the plot for particular small amounts of data

Comment: @Psidom is correct - if you have a count variable already, you don't need a histogram.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408506/make-a-histogram-whos-frequency-is-a-value-in-the-row/31408618#31408618

Comment: These are a few examples of erroneous plots.  I have hundreds of others all using the same script.  And as I mentioned, if the number of values is < 2 or > 4, it looks ok.  I don't want to have to finesse the graphs, I just want to run one script.  I think this is a bug in R or ggplot2, not user error

Comment: @slashdottir you might as well provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), since you'd need to do that for a bug report anyway

Comment: Already did?  All the code to produce the graph is already in the question

Comment: @slashdottir you did not provide a "minimal dataset and minimal runnable code" - please read my link. Also your example is very confusing because...

Comment: ...you have a column called `count` in your dataset and then `geom_histogram` aggregates these records by count (not sum) into another variable called `count`.  Is that really what you want? I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: The datasets are provided - directly underneath each plot.  The plot.r script is there and so is the command line call to run it.  What do you feel is missing?

Comment: Where do you feel a 'sum' is required?  Not following

Comment: Your problem is the `limits` and the bar is out of the range of the `limits` you set up. If you expand the limits to a larger range, the bar appears.

Comment: @Psidom Can you give specifics.  I cannot see any data that is outside the limit?

Comment: Your data is not outside the range, but when you use histogram, it will cut your variable and redefine the bucket for your data. I do not know how to fix it, but `limits=as.Date(c('2016-09-01','2017-02-10'))` will show the bars.

Comment: Hmm.  I tried your suggestion and get two really fat bars that don't reflect the data accurately.

Comment: It does seem like a bug, considering the difference between the behavior of one point and two points plot.

Comment: @Psidom  Thanks, at least I know that it's not my script

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug, I think it is actually by design and the bars are getting clipped as they spill over into the limits.

I also think this is more of a `geom_bar` than a `geom_histogram` as this doesn't seem to be distribution data, but that is irrelevant to the issue, both behave the same.

One solution it is to set the `width` parameter explicitly in `geom_histo` instead of letting it be calculated:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=day, y=count, fill=account, labels=TRUE)) 
p <- p + geom_histogram(stat="identity",width=1) 
p <- p + scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%b-%Y"), limits=as.Date(c('2016-10-1','2017-01-01')))
p <- p + theme(legend.position="bottom")
p <- p + guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=5, byrow=TRUE))
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(size=15)) 
p<-p+labs(title=thetitle)
```

Then your two point example that is blank above gives you this - which seems right:

[image]

Can't be sure that setting the width explicitly will work when you have a lot of data though and the bars keep needing to get smaller - I suppose you could set it conditionally.

Comment: Thanks, looks like you got something that works.  I will try it.  Although I can't see how the bars are getting clipped by the limits as the data is inside it.

Comment: Probably clipping using the edges of the bars as the criterion. I suppose that could be considered a bug. Could file it on github and see what Hadley and co say about it.

Comment: stopped caring - just lost my job..  :/

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hope you get something better.